# Unary Minus vs Binop Minus

Tags: syntactic-sugar, unary-operator, binary-operators

My Question is; When writing a compiler, is it valid in all cases, to desuger unary minus, to the binary minus, with first operand = 0, that is can I change;

```
-x
```

to:

```
0-x
```

or will desugering alike this yield issues down the line?

Comment: What kind of compiler? For your own language definition, or an existing language?

Comment: For integers, it's fine. For floating-point, it does not do what the programmer expects when (s)he writes `-0.0` (the IEEE 754 rule is that 0.0 - 0.0 makes 0.0).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: When do you care if you get -0.0 or 0.0?

Comment: @Skeen If you are going to divide one by it, if you are going to inspect the sign later through any of the means available, … Signed zero is just there, in Java as in most other languages. You said “a subset of Java” but you did not say whether that subset had an intersection with floating-point. If it has an intersection at all, it would be simpler to just offer -0.0 (Note that it's possible not to offer it, the Go language omitted it, for instance). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: To clarify, Go has a unary minus that behaves as expected for floating-point values (dynamically mapping -0.0 to +0.0 and +0.0 to -0.0). But its grammar includes a notion of “constant expression”, evaluated at compile-time, in which `-` applied to `0.0` yields `0.0`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: The subset I'm working with does not currently support floating-point numbers, however it's not unlikely, that I'll expend the subset that I'm implementing. - However I'll just handle the unary minus explicitly then :), thanks.